# Receiving data from Firestore with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, google-cloud-firestore

this question is probably really easy but I kind of got stuck with Firestore. It's my first project with firestore + js and I'm trying to receive and display data from my database. I have a feeling that I am doing something really stupid because it seems like I am looping through my data and overriding it that's why I can see only one article element even though there should be 2 fetched from the database.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', event => {
  const app = firebase.app();
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const myProducts = db.collection('products');
  myProducts.onSnapshot(products => {
    const productsContainer = document.querySelector('#products__container');
    products.forEach(doc => {
      data = doc.data();
      console.log(data);
      let productMarkup = `<article id="${doc.id}">
        <h4>${data.name}</h4>
        <p>${data.price}</p>
      </article>`;
      productsContainer.innerHTML = productMarkup;
      console.log(productMarkup);
    });
  });
});
```

[image: Here is what I can see in my console.log]

Comment: You keep reassigning the innerhtml of products container at each iteration of the loop.  This is also a really inefficient way of generating Dom elements, I'd recommend declaring a document fragment before the foeach loop and then append children to the fragment, after the loop completes inject the doc fragment into the Dom :)

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for pointing out my mistake. I took different approach. If you have time to take a look and give some feedback if you find it more optimal than my previous code I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

After Alex suggestion, I decided to take the different approach to create DOM elements

````
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const myProducts = db.collection('products');
  const productsContainer = document.querySelector('#products__container');

  function renderProduct(doc) {
    const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let article = document.createElement('article');
    let productName = document.createElement('h4');
    let productPrice = document.createElement('p');

    article.setAttribute('id', doc.id);
    productName.textContent = doc.data().name;
    productPrice.textContent = doc.data().price;

    docFrag.appendChild(productName);
    docFrag.appendChild(productPrice);

    article.appendChild(docFrag);
    productsContainer.appendChild(article);
  }

  myProducts.onSnapshot(products => {
    products.forEach(doc => {
      data = doc.data();
      console.log(data);
      renderProduct(doc);
    });
  });
});```
````